# Visualising connections between scientific papers

Tags: publications, citations, reference-managers

So i just began to write my literature review and have a big bunch of research papers saved in a folder.

Is there a tool that would help me visualize the references between those papers saved in my folder?

I.e. for example paper A mentioned paper B in its bibliography, and B referenced C, C referenced D and E, A referenced E.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there is a good way to visualize the connection between the references that I am aware of. However, a good way to manage and organize references is using the free tool called Zotero (https://www.zotero.org/) where you can create tags, directories and subdirectories. So, may be using these you can group similar references into one category. It also has plugins for all the popular browsers and also a standalone version, so you can pretty quickly import references and build your library and it also supports all the popular formats for bibliography. There is also an online account that you can create to manage your library over the cloud.

Comment: The first sentence is an answer the question. The rest is not.  While useful advice (or perhaps just an advert). When the "helpful advise" part of your answer is 5 times longer than the part that answers the question. Then it suggests you have gone off topic